# Oh My ZSH & Vim Insert Cursor

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Currently using Oh My ZSH, however, when using Vim in INSERT mode, at the end of a line, when using arrows to navigate, the insert mode ends when you hit the end of the line, making it impossible to delete the last character on the line, following is my Theme file, can anybody help me out with this?

https://github.com/andrew8088/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/doubleend.zsh-theme

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not recommended to move around in insert mode at all. if you want to delete the last character on the line, just hit `$x` in normal mode. To delete the last character on the line and go to insert mode, use `$s`.

In most cases you should move much faster in normal mode usign `w`,`e`,`^` and the like, than using the arrows in insert mode. Why use vim if you use it like a notepad application?

Hope this helps

Comment: It does help, however, I still can't insert after the last character on the line. Unless I type, hit $x to delete whatever the last char was